# How to cut a plane in a user-designed object using vtk?

Tags: c++, image, vtk

For example, I want to design a sphere whose radius is 256 and origin is (0.0,0.0,0.0). And also I want to cut a plane through its origin and display the cross-section.
I look up the wiki of vtk of how to generate a sphere :http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Sphere and how to slice an image after reading some pics:http://www.vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/ImageProcessing/Cxx/ImageSlicing.cxx .
I want to combine the two pieces of codes together to accomplish this. But it fails.Because it says that the input of vtkImageReslice should be an object of class vtkImageData but actually it is vtkPloyData.So how to change the vtkPolyData into vtkImageData?Here is my code.

```
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkImageReader2.h"
#include "vtkMatrix4x4.h" 
#include "vtkImageReslice.h"
#include "vtkLookupTable.h"
#include "vtkImageMapToColors.h"
#include "vtkImageActor.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"
#include "vtkInteractorStyleImage.h"
#include "vtkCommand.h"
#include "vtkImageData.h"
#include "vtkImageMapper3D.h"
#include "vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline.h"
#include "vtkInformation.h"
#include "vtkSphereSource.h"
// The mouse motion callback, to turn "Slicing" on and off
class vtkImageInteractionCallback : public vtkCommand
{
public:

static vtkImageInteractionCallback *New() {
    return new vtkImageInteractionCallback;
};

vtkImageInteractionCallback() {
    this->Slicing = 0;
    this->ImageReslice = 0;
    this->Interactor = 0;
};

void SetImageReslice(vtkImageReslice *reslice) {
    this->ImageReslice = reslice;
};

vtkImageReslice *GetImageReslice() {
    return this->ImageReslice;
};

void SetInteractor(vtkRenderWindowInteractor *interactor) {
    this->Interactor = interactor;
};

vtkRenderWindowInteractor *GetInteractor() {
    return this->Interactor;
};

virtual void Execute(vtkObject *, unsigned long event, void *)
{
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor *interactor = this->GetInteractor();

    int lastPos[2];
    interactor->GetLastEventPosition(lastPos);
    int currPos[2];
    interactor->GetEventPosition(currPos);

    if (event == vtkCommand::LeftButtonPressEvent)
    {
        this->Slicing = 1;
    }
    else if (event == vtkCommand::LeftButtonReleaseEvent)
    {
        this->Slicing = 0;
    }
    else if (event == vtkCommand::MouseMoveEvent)
    {
        if (this->Slicing)
        {
            vtkImageReslice *reslice = this->ImageReslice;

            // Increment slice position by deltaY of mouse
            int deltaY = lastPos[1] - currPos[1];

            reslice->Update();
            double sliceSpacing = reslice->GetOutput()->GetSpacing()[2];
            vtkMatrix4x4 *matrix = reslice->GetResliceAxes();
            // move the center point that we are slicing through
            double point[4];
            double center[4];
            point[0] = 0.0;
            point[1] = 0.0;
            point[2] = sliceSpacing * deltaY;
            point[3] = 1.0;
            matrix->MultiplyPoint(point, center);
            matrix->SetElement(0, 3, center[0]);
            matrix->SetElement(1, 3, center[1]);
            matrix->SetElement(2, 3, center[2]);
            interactor->Render();
        }
        else
        {
            vtkInteractorStyle *style = vtkInteractorStyle::SafeDownCast(
                interactor->GetInteractorStyle());
            if (style)
            {
                style->OnMouseMove();
            }
        }
    }
};

private:

// Actions (slicing only, for now)
int Slicing;

// Pointer to vtkImageReslice
vtkImageReslice *ImageReslice;

// Pointer to the interactor
vtkRenderWindowInteractor *Interactor;
};

// The program entry point
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Generate a sphere whose radius is 256.0 and origin is (0.0,0.0,0.0)
vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphere = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
sphere->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
sphere->SetRadius(256.0);
sphere->Update();

static double sagittalElements[16] = {
    0, 0, -1, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, -1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1 };


// Set the slice orientation
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> resliceAxes =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
resliceAxes->DeepCopy(sagittalElements);
// Set the point through which to slice
resliceAxes->SetElement(0, 3, 0);
resliceAxes->SetElement(1, 3, 0);
resliceAxes->SetElement(2, 3, 0);

// Extract a slice in the desired orientation
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> reslice =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
reslice->SetInputConnection(sphere->GetOutputPort());
reslice->SetOutputDimensionality(2);
reslice->SetResliceAxes(resliceAxes);
reslice->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();

// Create a greyscale lookup table
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> table =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
table->SetRange(0, 2000); // image intensity range
table->SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0); // from black to white
table->SetSaturationRange(0.0, 0.0); // no color saturation
table->SetRampToLinear();
table->Build();

// Map the image through the lookup table
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors> color =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors>::New();
color->SetLookupTable(table);
color->SetInputConnection(reslice->GetOutputPort());

// Display the image
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> actor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
actor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(color->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(actor);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> window =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
window->AddRenderer(renderer);

// Set up the interaction
vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage> imageStyle =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
interactor->SetInteractorStyle(imageStyle);
window->SetInteractor(interactor);
window->Render();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageInteractionCallback> callback =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageInteractionCallback>::New();
callback->SetImageReslice(reslice);
callback->SetInteractor(interactor);

imageStyle->AddObserver(vtkCommand::MouseMoveEvent, callback);
imageStyle->AddObserver(vtkCommand::LeftButtonPressEvent, callback);
imageStyle->AddObserver(vtkCommand::LeftButtonReleaseEvent, callback);

// Start interaction
// The Start() method doesn't return until the window is closed by the user
interactor->Start();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks
Kun Yang

Comment: Here you can see a little sample of how to convert an vtkPolyData into vtkImageData : https://cmake.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/PolyDataToImageData

Answer (score 0):

No conversion needed. Use vtkClipPolydata which is a poly -> poly filter.